# Rotate an image inside a canvas and download the rotated image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I am trying to rotate an image and save it after that. 
My problem isn't the rotation, but when I save the image, the image does not have the rotation.

The code is:

```
rotate = (value) => {
     //get canvas context
    const ctx = this.canvasRef.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = this.state.imgsource;
    var cw = img.width, ch = img.height, cx = 0, cy = 0;
    value = this.state.cont + value;
    //   Calculate new canvas size and x/y coorditates for image

    //rotation Code here

 //setting state of rotation
    if (this.state.cont == 270 || this.state.cont == -270) {
        this.setState({ cont: 0 });
    } else {
        this.setState({ cont: value });
    }
      //draw the image with the rotation
    this.canvasRef.setAttribute('width', cw);
    this.canvasRef.setAttribute('height', ch);
    ctx.rotate(value * Math.PI / 180);
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy);
    };
    ctx.save();
  //getting the last state of the image 
    this.setState({ imgsource: img.src });

}
```

Comment: Image loading is an asynchronous action so you would have to save the context after the image is loaded. then update the state.

Comment: You're rotating the canvas's context not the image, you need to get the new rotated image from the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Image loading is an asynchronous action so you would have to save the context after the image is loaded. then update the state.

```
rotate = (value) => {
     //get canvas context
    const ctx = this.canvasRef.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = this.state.imgsource;
    var cw = img.width, ch = img.height, cx = 0, cy = 0;
    value = this.state.cont + value;
    //   Calculate new canvas size and x/y coorditates for image

    //rotation Code here

 //setting state of rotation
    if (this.state.cont == 270 || this.state.cont == -270) {
        this.setState({ cont: 0 });
    } else {
        this.setState({ cont: value });
    }
      //draw the image with the rotation
    this.canvasRef.setAttribute('width', cw);
    this.canvasRef.setAttribute('height', ch);
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy);
        ctx.rotate(value * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.save();
        this.setState({ imgsource: img.src });
    };
  //getting the last state of the image 

}
```